# Any alternate method to allocate free space without growpart?

Tags: linux, lvm

I am trying to allocate free space to root as my disk space is full (I am using this guide https://guideplanet.co.uk/index.php/2021/03/26/lvm-extention-for-centos/). I am doing it via KVM (ionos hosting). But i am not able to install growpart as it throws no disk space error.

Any alternate method to do?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: See https://itsfoss.com/free-up-space-ubuntu-linux/ , where can be found some tips to get free space on drive.

Comment: @Mihai8, OP talk about about RPM based distribution (RHEL, CentOS), see `yum` in the screenshot. Some of the tips may work, some not.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to clear the `yum` cache and try again:

```
yum clean all
```

Also you can check in `/var/log` about old log files and delete (eventually) some of them or truncate them.